# schema to data frame using pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, schema

I have this schema:

```
schm = StructType([
        StructField("User ID", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("Tag", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Activated", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Created Date", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Updated Date", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Valid Until", StringType(), True),
        StructField("last used", StringType(), True),
        StructField("reference", StringType(), True),
        StructField("employee code", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("Unique user ID", IntegerType(), True),
    ])
schm
```

I want to build a dataframe for 998 values.But the problem is i can't understand how to get input data for 998 rows(same value for 998 rows):

```
df = create_df(spark, input_data, schm)
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case? It's unclear.

Comment: If your use case is just to create DataFrame try using `df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, schm)`